# Why did my router randomly assign wireless devices to br0 interface?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, tomato

So I have a WRT54GL router with Tomato firmware on. I have few wireless devices on my network. Most of the time they work fine, but occasionally, some devices that were previously on router's eth1 interface (as seen from the router's device list admin page) were switched to br0 and when they're on br0, they don't have access to the network at all (even 192.168.1.1)

Anyone knows why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: br0 is the bridge - were you trying to bridge interfaces?

Comment: No. I weren't doing anything special. They switch interfaces silently and apparently randomly...